Magnetising Inductance / Primary Inductance
I provided a picture below which shows the transformer calculations and LTspice simulation.
In the 1'st picture L11 = 100.5 µH. This value is the inductance of primary side of the transformer.
In the 2'nd picture the calculated values are used in Ltspice. Here is my question :
L11 which is inductance of the primary side is calculated/defined somehow. It is 100.5 uH and leakage is 0.5 µH. But there is 10 mH in the primary side as well in 2'nd picture. Where does this come from? there is no calculation in the video about this.
As far as I know Lm (magnetising inductance) is same as L11. If they are same, why are they separated as 100 µH and 10 mH? This is the point which makes me very confused?
In other word, If I calculated my primary inductance for a different application, how will I know how to separate it as in the case of 100.5 µH and 10 mH?

[Transformer calculations]
Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VrIfvNVBSyE

[Ltspice simulation]
Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VrIfvNVBSyE

You're modelling the magnetizing inductance as 100 uH on the primary.  Therefore, the reflected inductance on the secondary is the turns ratio squared times the inductance on the primary, or 1010100 uH, which is 10 mH.  Other than that, I'm not sure I understand your question.

I am not talking about the secondary, if the magnetising inductance (which the primary inductance) is defined as 100uH then why it is seperated as 100uH and 10mH on the primary ? This is my question.  @John D

@Rohat Kılıç your comments are valuable for me. Could you help about this topic ?

The 10 mH is just for modeling, it should be infinite but LTspice can’t handle infinite. Feel free to change it on L3 and L4 to 10 H.

Thanks sir. Then some other questions come to my mind according to your  comments:

Why should L3 be infinite ?
So whatever I put it on L3, wouldn't it effect anything ?
About L4, it should be L4= Lk2+n^2.100uH  according to the first picture but it is Lk2+n^2.10mH  in the second picture for the secondary side ? Doesn't seem to be wrong ?
@winny


Secondary inductance shouldn’t be a hard-coded value but only a ratio (squared) to L3. Google transformer modeling and read up why an impossible number like infinity would appear is a model of an actual transformer.

If you know something, why do you prefer to act like it is a secret information ? I asked 3 brief question based on your comments but ı couldnt get any answer.  @winny

Deeper learning from finding out something yourself, especially simulate and test a theory.


if the magnetising inductance (which the primary inductance) is defined as 100uH then why it is seperated as 100uH and 10mH on the primary ? This is my question.

Without the parasitics, a real-world transformer model is like following:

Image nicked from my answer here. You can also have a look at there for some other useful details.
\$L_p\$ is the primary magnetising inductance, and the transformer in the red dashed box is an ideal transformer. Ideal transformers have infinite inductances i.e. all that matters is the turns ratio, therefore when you measure the primary inductance with an LCR meter for example, it'll show you the parallel equivalent of both which is equal to \$L_p\$ because of the infinite inductance in parallel.
In order for a real transformer to work (i.e. to get transformer action which covers include voltage conversion and energy transfer), the core needs to be magnetised and de-magnetised (reset). Remember (or study if needed) the B-H loop at this point. So the magnetisation and de-magnetisation is done via \$L_p\$.
As explained in my answer linked above, the primary current has two components: magnetising current and energy-related current. The former is always there, you can't get rid of it even if there's nothing attached to the secondary. The latter is the reflection of the current that your load draws.
For example, for a transformer with 1:10 ratio, if the secondary voltage is 50V then the primary voltage is 5V; and if the secondary current is 1A then the primary current is 10A (the relation between currents are inverse of the turns ratio). These currents are \$i_O\$ and \$i_L\$ in the above model. But there's also a magnetising current, and it's always there i.e. when there's primary voltage then there's primary magnetising current.

If you want to measure the magnetising currents and energy-related currents separately in a simulation environment, you can do this with the 2nd diagram in the last image in your question. Because modelling/sim software (e.g. LTspice) can't work with infinite numbers, the L3 must be large enough so that the equivalent with L5 (magnetising inductance) can be quite close to L5. 100 uH and 10m in parallel gives 91 uH. Fair enough, but I'd select 1 H or even 1 kH. Note that L4 must be adjusted in accordance with L3 to get the desired turns ratio: \$L_3/L_4=(np/ns)^2\$. So, if \$np/ns = 1/n\$ then \$L_4=n^2 \ L_3\$.
So, \$L_3 = 10\ \text{mH}\$ and \$L_4 = n^2 \ L_3\$ are to simulate the turns ratio of the ideal transformer (that's why they are big numbers but, as I said, I'd use bigger numbers), and \$L_3 = 10\ \mu\text{H}\$ is to simulate the magnetising inductance.


As far as I know Lm (magnetising inductance) is same as L11.

That is incorrect.
$$L_{11} = L_m + L_{k1}$$
So, they \$L_{11}\$ and \$L_m\$ differ by the primary leakage inductance \$L_{k1}\$.

why are they separated as 100 µH and 10 mH?

The 100 uH is the magnetizing inductance seen from the primary side. The 10 mH is the magnetizing inductance seen from the secondary side. They differ by a factor of \$n^2\$, or in this case, \$10^2=100\$. 100 x 100 uH is 10 mH.
If we place an impedance on one side of an ideal transformer, and try to measure that impedance seen on the other side of the transformer, it will appear "magnified" by a factor of \$n^2\$, where \$n\$ is the "turns ratio" of the ideal transformer. That is, \$n\$ is the ratio by which a voltage on the primary side is "magnified" on the secondary side.
